# Uncertainty over set of slopes from least-squares

Tags: least-squares, experiment-design, standard-error, uncertainty

I got several slopes, of the same measurement, taken in different samplings. All slopes come from least-squares fit, which allows to determine a stadard error associated to that slope, but how do I take repeatibility of the measured slopes into account, so I can have a mean slope and a associated uncertainty where all the standard errors of each slope are taken into account?